# Example or tutorial of creating RDF/OWL Semantic Metadata model from C# classes

Tags: c#, rdf, dotnetrdf

I need to create RDF/OWL Semantic Metadata model from C# classes.
In other words, there are a couple of C# classes, one of them refers to another through a property and I need to create RDF/OWL Metadata model based on these classes and their connections.

I’ve found this two libraries [dotnetRDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotNetRDF/2.2.0-pre0001), [RDFSharp.Semantics](https://github.com/mdesalvo/RDFSharp.Semantics) for working with RDF in .NET.

But I can’t find any tutorials or examples, or some detailed documentation for these libraries to understand how to create RDF/OWL Metadata, is it passable at all…

I would be very grateful if someone could share a link to examples or tutorials, or may be a code snippet.

Comment: Hi @Art, and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately a question asking for links to resources such as tutorials is considered off-topic here, so this question is likely to be put on hold or closed. Having said that, the dotnetrdf website (at http://www.dotnetrdf.org/) has a large number of resources, including a user guide and a developers guide. They seem ideal places to get started.

Comment: strange that you're not able to find the [docs](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki) for dotnetrdf ...